# Creating a custom UIView that just acts just as a gif

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm rather new to iOS programming and Objective-C in general.

What I have is a bunch of images named "image0.png", "image1.png", ... ,"image47.png" that form an animated image. First I created a button that when pressed, began the animation.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

...

- (IBAction)startAnimation {
  self.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray array];
  for (int i = 0; i < 48; ++i) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    self.imageView.animationImages = [self.imageView.animationImages arrayByAddingObject:image];
  }
  self.imageView.animationDuration = 5.0;
  [self.imageView startAnimating];
}
```

This worked perfectly fine, except you had to press the button to start. I wanted the animated image to begin immediately without having to press anything. What I tried to do was give the `imageView` a custom `UIImageView` class. Then in the `customImageView.m` file I shoved the above code into the `initWithFrame:` method.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    self.animationImages = [NSArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; ++i)
      self.animationImages = [self.animationImages arrayByAddingObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png", i]]];
    self.animationDuration = 5.0;
    [self startAnimating];
  }
  return self;
}
```

However, now nothing happens. I've also tried moving the `[self startAnimating]` line back to an `IBAction`, but still nothing.

Comment: Do you mean the animation works fine when you press the button. otherwise not

Comment: Yes, for the first hunk of code. But I'd like to remove the need of pressing a button.

Comment: Are you assigning UIImageView from nib ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code you have in `startAnimation` into `ViewDidAppear` instead. It will start **animating** as soon as the `controller's` view appears.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to call this method on `viewWillAppear`. You can also do this.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
     [self performSelector:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}
```